# Display SOTR text for lable in SRM UI Addon

Tags: sapui5

I'm following the Extensibility Cookbook SP07. I can't seem to display our custom label in product details page. We have already the OTR-Texts in SOTR_EDIT. We did not configure the SPRO because we are getting the odata from via the old way (binding the zfields to our controls).

I'm trying to access the label via this code

```
 new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text : Appcc.getText("ZMAXORDER") + ":" })
```

I'm not sure if I miss something or if the code I have is wrong.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: We need more.. are there errors in the console? Is the label rendered to the DOM tree (but the text is missing)? Can you provide a minimal example via JSBin?

Comment: The app is showing ZMAXORDER instead of the real text "Max Quantity Order" NO errors in the console so far.

Comment: What is `Appcc` exactly? Did you debug the `getText` function?

Comment: Appcc is the textManager. How do you debug getText?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools Set a breakpoint, jump in the method, look what it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Appcc.getTetx("ZMAXORDER")` the application will query the text for alias `/SRMNXP/UI/ZMAXORDER`. If it does not exists (I assume it does not), then `ZMAXORDER` is displayed.

`Appcc` is not the `textManager`, it is the application controller, what uses the text manager to retrieve OTR texts.

Comment: You are right. ZMAXORDER does not exist on the /SRMNXP/UI. But how do you call then if ZMAXORDER is exisitng on another path say /ZSRMNXP/UI?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a implementation in `BADI /SRMNXP/BD_CHANGE_DATA`, add your custom text in export param `cr_entity_set` when the import param `iv_entity_name = 'TEXT'`. As tekan wrote, the `cr_entity_set-alias_name` is `/SRMNXP/UI/ZMAXORDER` or `/DUMMY/UI5/ZMAXORDER`, and `cr_entity_set-short_text` is your text.